# android generating 7 bit checksum for passing data to a bluetooth module

Tags: java, hex, byte, checksum, 7-bit

I'm creating an application to send data to a bluetooth module.

I'm having a tough time following the provided documentation. Can anyone help me understand how to create the checksum as mentioned (Byte No. 3)

So far, I have been able to make a sum of address 1 & 2 by converting them into integers and adding them up, the rest is beyond me... how do I take a bit-inverse and apply a 7-bit checksum and turn it into a "7-bit data with 0x7F" ??

[image: The module communication document]

Comment: I wont down vote, but you didn't provide any attempt, any code at all....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0x7F means 0b01111111 in binary and represents a bit mask.
You have to do a bitwise and with your checksum like that

```
result = checksum & 0x7F
```

EDIT

As long i understand, it schould be

```
checksum = ~( byte1 + byte2 )
```

Comment: Apologies for a noob question, but how do I get the checksum as mentioned above? a tiny code snipped would be great!